# Moment time shows midnight, _i and _d properties do not match

Tags: momentjs

I'm using moment.js in my web application and encountered a bug where the time on many objects change to midnight at some point.  I'm still trying to hunt down what, if anything triggers this change, but looking at one of the moments, I noticed the _i property shows the original / correct time.

Below is the developer console output of one of the moments in question, `mm`

```
_d: Thu Apr 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"
_i: "2015-04-02T12:10:43-04:00"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale
_pf: Object
_tzm: -240

mm.toISOString()
// "2015-04-02T04:00:00.000Z"

moment(mm._i).toISOString()
// "2015-04-02T16:10:43.000Z"
```

What does the _i represent, and why doesn't it match the string output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out the bug was caused by a combination of 2 bad assumptions I had

1. calling `startOf()` mutates the moment, which I did not realize
2. the Immutable data structure I'm using ignores Objects with custom prototypes, so the moment objects were left mutable

The result was that another part of the application was able to mutate moments that I expected to be immutable

To answer my question though, I found the following

`_i` is the input when the moment object was originally created, and does not appear to change

`_d` is a `Date` object representing the date value after any mutations

```
mm = moment("2015-04-02T12:10:43-04:00")
mm._i // "2015-04-02T12:10:43-04:00"
mm._d // Thu Apr 02 2015 12:10:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)

mm.startOf('day')
mm._i // "2015-04-02T12:10:43-04:00"
mm._d // Thu Apr 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: Neither `_i` nor `_d` should be used.  These are internal-only properties.  In particular, `_d` may or may not need to be combined with other internal properties to achieve the desired results.  Use the public API functions only.